# Trying to display image on screen in Java, doesn't work

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I have two classes. Class GUI extends `JFrame` and is supposed to display on the screen a `JPanel`, which is class Surface that extends `JPanel`.

Class Surface has a paintComponent method which should display an image, but for some reason it won't display it. Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    GUI(){
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI(){
        Surface s = new Surface();
        add(s);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    } 

} 

import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

public class Surface extends JPanel {

    Image image;
    ImageIcon ii;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 

        super.paintComponent(g); 

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; 

        ii = new ImageIcon("redsquare.png"); 
        image = ii.getImage(); 

        Dimension d = new Dimension(); 
        d.width = image.getWidth(null); 
        d.height = image.getHeight(null); 
        this.setPreferredSize(d); 

        g2d.drawImage(image,50,50,null); 

    } 

}
```

Comment: Where is your png file located? Put it to project root folder.

Comment: never to load image inside paintComponent (ii = new ImageIcon("redsquare.png");), create a local variable for this Object

Comment: As an aside, this could be achieved by displaying the image in a `JLabel` with a 50px `EmptyBorder`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems problem in your file location, try next code for getting png from resources of project:

```
ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("redsquare.png"));
```

for that example `redsquare.png` file in the same package as `Surface` class.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans, using this relative path **"redsquare.png"**, you image needs to be directly in the project root

```
ProjectRoot
         redsquare.png
         src
         bin
```

Also, listen to the wise words of @mKorbel

> *"never to load image inside paintComponent (ii = new ImageIcon("redsquare.png");), create a local variable for this Object"* -@mKorbel

Also, for embedded resources, you should really consider @alex2410's answer. You want to load the images from the class.

Answer (score 0):

May be problem with the image location it seems
Try to run with different image source

Comment: I'd normally say "this is not an answer, but might make a good comment".  OTOH that has been noted before in this thread, and is just noise.